# Which one is the best answer?

Tags: american-english, infinitive-vs-gerund

1．________ by his look, he doesn't think much of our plan.

A．Judging   B．Judged
C．To judge  D．Being Judged

Which one is correct ? Why?

Answer (score 1):

I think choice A is correct. Because firstly, JUDGING BY/FROM is a fixed expression being used in english. And secondly, the one who is judging here in this sentence is not He (the subject of the second clause) but someone else, so I suppose choice A is correct.

Comment: I agree it's A.